# react js with dynamic routing .not able to fetch the data from fake json server

Tags: reactjs, routes

when i click on the image item the detail page should be open coontaing all the details of that particular image..i am not able to fetch the ingrdients part and the details are getting from the json server the folling code is:

home.js

```
import Homeview from './Homeview/Homeview'

export default class Home extends Component {

    state= {
        img : []
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/food')
        .then(res=>{
            const data = res.data
            this.setState({
                img : data
            })
        })
    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <Homeview homeview= {this.state.img}/>
        )
    }
}
```

homeview.js

```
const Homeview = (props) => {

const {homeview} = props 
return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        {homeview.map((e)=>{
            return(
                <div key={e.id}>
                    <Link to={`/Home/`+e.id}><img className={styles.img} src={e.imageURL} alt="something"/></Link>
                </div>
            )

    })}
    </div>
    
)
}

export default Homeview
```

homedetail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


const url = "http://localhost:3001/food"
export default class Homedetail extends Component {

state= {
    topicd : ''
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`${url}/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
    .then(res=>{
        const data = res.data
       // console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            topicd:data
        })
    })
}
render() {

    console.log(this.state.topicd.ingredients)

    let ingredients =null

    if(ingredients===true){
        ingredients = this.state.topicd.ingredients.map((e)=>{
            return(
                <div>
                    <p>{e.name}</p>
                    <p>{e.type}</p>
                </div>
            ) 
        })
        return ingredients
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.state.topicd.name}</h2>
            {ingredients}
            {/* {this.state.topicd.food.ingredients.map((e)=>{
                return (
                    <div>
                        {e.name}
                        {e.type}
                    </div>
                )
            })} */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

db.json

```
{
    "food":
    [
    {   
        "id":1,
        "name": "Crock Pot Roast",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "1 package",
                "name": "brown gravy mix",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 package",
                "name": "dried Italian salad dressing mix",
                "type": "Condiments"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 package",
                "name": "dry ranch dressing mix",
                "type": "Condiments"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                "name": "water",
                "type": "Drinks"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Place meet roast in crock pot.",
            "\t Mix the dried mixes together in a bowl and sprinkle over the roast.",
            "\t Pour the water around the roast.",
            "\t Cook on low for 7-9 hours."
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://img.sndimg.com/food/image/upload/w_266/v1/img/recipes/27/20/8/picVfzLZo.jpg",
        "originalURL": "http://www.food.com/recipe/to-die-for-crock-pot-roast-27208"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": "Roasted Asparagus",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "1 lb",
                "name": " asparagus",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 1/2 tbsp",
                "name": "olive oil",
                "type": "Condiments"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 tsp",
                "name": "kosher salt",
                "type": "Baking"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Preheat oven to 425°F.",
            "\t Cut off the woody bottom part of the asparagus spears and discard.",
            "\t With a vegetable peeler, peel off the skin on the bottom 2-3 inches of the spears (this keeps the asparagus from being all.\",string.\", and if you eat asparagus you know what I mean by that).",
            "\t Place asparagus on foil-lined baking sheet and drizzle with olive oil.",
            "\t Sprinkle with salt.",
            "\t With your hands roll the asparagus around until they are evenly coated with oil and salt.",
            "\t Roast for 10-15 minutes, depending on the thickness of your stalks.",
            "\t They should be handeled gentally when pierced with the tip of a knife.",
            "\t The tips of the spears turn to deep brown but observe them keenly, to avoid burning.",
            "\t They are plain, its good to serve them with a light vinaigrette. If need something add spices to balance the meal."
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://img.sndimg.com/food/image/upload/w_266/v1/img/recipes/50/84/7/picMcSyVd.jpg",
        "originalURL": "http://www.food.com/recipe/roasted-asparagus-50847"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": "Curried Lentils and Rice",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "1 quart",
                "name": "beef broth",
                "type": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 cup",
                "name": "dried green lentils",
                "type": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                "name": "basmati rice",
                "type": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tsp",
                "name": "curry powder",
                "type": "Condiments"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tsp",
                "name": "salt",
                "type": "Condiments"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Bring broth to a low boil.",
            "\t Add curry powder and salt.",
            "\t Cook lentils for 20 minutes.",
            "\t Add rice and simmer for 20 minutes.",
            "\t Enjoy!"
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://dagzhsfg97k4.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/lentils3.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "Big Night Pizza",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "5 teaspoons",
                "name": "yeast",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "5 cups",
                "name": "flour",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "4 tablespoons",
                "name": "vegetable oil",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 tablespoons",
                "name": "sugar",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 teaspoons",
                "name": "salt",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 cups",
                "name": "hot water",
                "type": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/4 cup",
                "name": "pizza sauce",
                "type": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "3/4 cup",
                "name": "mozzarella cheese",
                "type": "Dairy"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Add hot water to yeast in a large bowl and let all them to mix well for 15 minutes.",
            "\t Add oil, sugar, salt and flour and allow them to mix well for next hour.",
            "\t Knead the dough and spread it on a pan.",
            "\t Spread pizza sauce and add the cheese.",
            "\t Garnish it with toppings.",
            "\t Bake at 400°F for 15 minutes.",
            "\t Enjoy!"
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Spinach_pizza.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "name": "Cranberry and Apple Stuffed Acorn Squash Recipe",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "2",
                "name": "acorn squash",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": "boiling water",
                "type": "Drinks"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2",
                "name": "apples chopped into 1.4 inch pieces",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                "name": "dried cranberries",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 teaspoon",
                "name": "cinnamon",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 tablespoons",
                "name": "melted butter",
                "type": "Dairy"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Cut squash in half, remove seeds.",
            "\t Place squash in baking dish, cut down the sides.",
            "\t Pour water to 1/4 th inch of bowl.",
            "\t Bake for 30 minutes at 350°F.",
            "\t In another large bowl, combine remaining ingredients.",
            "\t Remove squash from oven, fill with mix.",
            "\t Bake for 30-40 minutes more until squash tenders.",
            "\t Enjoy!"
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://elanaspantry.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/acorn_squash_with_cranberry.jpg",
        "originalURL": ""
    },
    {
        "id":6,
        "name": "Mic's Yorkshire Puds",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "200g",
                "name": "plain flour",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "3",
                "name": "eggs",
                "type": "Dairy"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "300ml",
                "name": "milk",
                "type": "Dairy"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "3 tbsp",
                "name": "vegetable oil",
                "type": "Condiments"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Put the flour and some seasoning into a large bowl.",
            "\t Keep adding eggs(one at a time).",
            "\t Whisk in milk until you have a smooth batter.",
            "\t Cool it in the fridge for at least 30 minutes.",
            "\t Heat oven to 22°C/gas mark it to 7.",
            "\t Pour the oil into the holes of muffin tin.",
            "\t Heat tin in the oven for 5 minutes.",
            "\t Ladle the batter into the tin.",
            "\t Bake for 30 minutes until well browned and risen."
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Yorkshire_Pudding.jpg",
        "originalURL": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Yorkshire_Pudding.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":7,
        "name": "Old-Fashioned Oatmeal Cookies",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "1 cup",
                "name": "raisins",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": "cup water",
                "type": "Drinks"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "3/4 cup",
                "name": "shortening",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 1/2 cups",
                "name": "sugar",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 1/2 cups",
                "name": "flour",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tsp.",
                "name": "soda",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tsp.",
                "name": "salt",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tsp.",
                "name": "cinnamon",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 tsp.",
                "name": "baking powder",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 tsp.",
                "name": "cloves",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2 cups",
                "name": "oats",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                "name": "chopped nuts",
                "type": "Baking"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Boil raisins with water over medium heat until they are plump, for about 15 minutes.",
            "\t Drain raisins, reserving the liquid.",
            "\t Add enough water to reserved liquid to measure 1/2 cup.",
            "\t Heat oven to 400°C.",
            "\t Mix it thoroughly with sugar, eggs and vanilla.",
            "\t Stir in reserved liquid.",
            "\t Blend in remaining ingredients.",
            "\t Drop dough by rounded teaspoon about 2 inches apart onto ungreased baking sheet.",
            "\t Bake for next 8 to 10 minutes.",
            "\t About six pieces of cookies."
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/gmi-digital-library/65caecf7-a8f7-4a09-8513-2659cf92871e.jpg",
        "originalURL": "#"
    },
    {
        "id":9,
        "name": "Curried chicken salad",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "3",
                "name": "skinless, boneless chicken breasts, halved lengthwise",
                "type": "Meat"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                "name": "mayonnaise",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tbsp",
                "name": "lemon zest",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 tbsp ",
                "name": "lemon juice",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1 1/2 tsp",
                "name": "curry powder",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/4 tsp",
                "name": "salt",
                "type": "Baking"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2",
                "name": "ripe mangoes, diced",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1/4 cup",
                "name": "dried cranberries",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "2",
                "name": "green onions, thinly sliced",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": "celery stalk, finely chopped",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "6 leaves",
                "name": "Boston lettuce",
                "type": "Produce"
            },
            {
                "quantity": "6",
                "name": "English muffins, toasted",
                "type": "Misc"
            }
        ],
        "steps": [
            "Arrange the chicken in a single layer within the large pot.",
            "\t Add water and boil chicken over medium-high.",
            "\t Flip chicken, reduce heat to medium and simmer until cooked, about 6 more min.",
            "\t Cool.",
            "\t Add mayo with lemon zest, juice, curry and salt in large bowl.",
            "\t Using 2 forks, shred chicken, then add mayo mixture with mango, cranberries, green onions and celery.",
            "\t Divide among muffins with lettuce leaves",
            "\t Serve the Sandwich with tops along with chicken"
        ],
        "imageURL": "http://www.chatelaine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Curried-chicken-salad.jpg",
        "originalURL": "http://www.chatelaine.com/recipe/stovetop-cooking-method/curried-chicken-salad/"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: add your `<Router/>` code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

i see you using the component/presentational pattern, but i dont see where did you call HomeDetail and where is the onClick function to handler the click you talk about, maybe im missing something,